# Mapping numeral marks to letter based marks

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to code a program to receive a number and map it to a letter grade based mark using javascript, and html.

When I run the code, I don't get any answers.

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
   <h1>mapping a numerical grade to a letter grade</h1>
    </header>

    <div class="column1">
      <div class="input">
        a <input id="number1" type="number" min=" -32768" max=" 32767" />
      </div>
      <div class="input">
        <button onclick="mapping()">enter</button>
      </div>
      <strong><p id="output"></p></strong>
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
  function mapping() {

  var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("number1").value);

  switch (true) {
    case a > 89:
      answer = "A+";
      break;
    case a > 79:
      answer = "A";
      break;
    case a > 74:
      answer = "B+";
      break;
    case a > 69:
      answer = "B";
      break;
    case a > 64:
      answer = "C+";
      break;
    case a > 59:
      answer = "C";
    case a > 54:
      answer = "D+";
    case a > 49:
      answer = "D";
      break;
    case a > 40:
      answer = "E";
      break;

    default:
      answer = "F";

      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = answer;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = answer;` is inside the switch statement. It will be executed with `default` only

This code will work:

```
function mapping() {
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("number1").value);

  switch (true) {
    case a > 89:
      answer = "A+";
      break;
    case a > 79:
      answer = "A";
      break;
    case a > 74:
      answer = "B+";
      break;
    case a > 69:
      answer = "B";
      break;
    case a > 64:
      answer = "C+";
      break;
    case a > 59:
      answer = "C";
    case a > 54:
      answer = "D+";
    case a > 49:
      answer = "D";
      break;
    case a > 40:
      answer = "E";
      break;

    default:
      answer = "F";
  }
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = answer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

switch (true) doesn't work. switch (1) does.

Also, I think case only accepts values, not comparisons -- at least when I tried it with Chrome and Opera. So you might want to rewrite this using if-else statements.